# Kali linux - unable to detect network when running airodump-ng wlan0mon

Tags: kali-linux, airodump-ng

When I am trying to run

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

I am not able to detect any network.

Note that Kali linux is installed on my HDD as a second operating system and the wireless adapter on my laptop is "Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter".

I tried all the suggestions that I saw, such as to run

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

And I tried

```
service network-manager stop
```

But nothing worked for me.

Here is a snapshot from what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by running

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```